# Button click event not firing inside Multiview?

Tags: asp.net

I have a user control with three Views inside MultiView, first two views contains different controls and each have a button to submit the form, both are working as expected. Third one has two asp image button both are not attached with any validation group, causes validation is also false but post back is not happening on clicking the button, there is no javascript error i already checked that, any help is appreciated. Following is markup.

```
<asp:View runat="server" ID="vwPayAsGuest">
        <asp:Panel ID="divButtons" runat="server" CssClass="creditcardbuttons-container">
            <div class="creditcardbuttons-container-left">
                &nbsp;</div>
            <div id="divRegularPayment" class="f-left">
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="lbtnRegularCheckout" ToolTip="Pay with credit card"
                    AlternateText="Pay with credit card" OnClick="lbtnRegularCheckout_OnClick" CausesValidation="false"/>
            </div>
            <div id="divPayByPayPal" class="f-left padding-left15">
                <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="submit" CausesValidation="false"
                    ImageUrl="https://fpdbs.paypal.com/dynamicimageweb?cmd=_dynamic-image&buttontype=ec-mark"
                    AlternateText="Pay via PayPal" ToolTip="Pay via PayPal (Express Checkout)" OnClick="lnkButPayPal_Click" />
            </div> 
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:View>
```

Comment: Did you try validationGroup for your validation controls and button that should fire validation as an alternative?

Comment: @NileshThakkar Yes, all other controls are associated with appropriate validation group.

Comment: You may want to check http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.in/2009/12/weird-causesvalidation-not-working.html